# R: Compare Multiple columns and characters in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns some of which contain individual characters for example:

```
test <- data.frame("IsA" = c("1.0", "0.5", "0.0"), "IsB" = c("1.0", "0.5", "0.0"), "IsC" = c("0.0", "0.5", "0.0"),  "C1" = c("a", "b", "c"), "C2"= c("a", "a", "c"), "C3" = c("a", "b", "b"), "C4" = c("c", "b", "c"))
```

Giving:

```
  IsA IsB IsC C1 C2 C3 C4
1 1.0 1.0 0.0  a  a  a  c
2 0.5 0.5 0.5  b  a  b  b
3 0.0 0.0 0.0  c  c  b  c
```

For each row I would like to add another 4 columns so that if C1 is "a" and "IsA" is greater than or equal to 0.05 the new column value is True.

```
  IsA IsB IsC C1 C2 C3 C4  C1.t  C2.t  C3.t  C4.t
1 1.0 1.0 0.0  a  a  a  c  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2 0.5 0.5 0.5  b  a  b  b  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
3 0.0 0.0 0.0  c  c  b  c FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not optimized for speed:

```
test <- cbind(test,
              t(apply(test, 1, function(x) {
                a <- as.numeric(x[1:3])
                names(a) <- letters[1:3]
                b <- x[-(1:3)]
                a[b] >= 0.05  
              })))

  IsA IsB IsC C1 C2 C3 C4     1     2     3     4
1 1.0 1.0 0.0  a  a  a  c  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2 0.5 0.5 0.5  b  a  b  b  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
3 0.0 0.0 0.0  c  c  b  c FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```